# Extending angular decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I'd like to make a custom decorator that would do some thing or other, and then call Angular's `Input` decorator, and used a bit like this:

```
@Component({
    template: '<h1 class="name">{{name}}</h1>
})
export class MyComponent {
    @CustomInput()
    private name: string;
}
```

I have managed to define a TypeScript decorator that does the extra things I want - this question is about how to call Angular's built-in decorators from within it.

```
export function CustomInput(inputName?: string) {
    return function (prototype: any, memberName: string) {
        // Create a default getter/setter property
        var backingMember = '__backingMember_' + memberName;
        var descriptor = {
            get: function () {
                return this[backingMember];
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this[backingMember] = value;
            }
        };

        // Make whatever changes I need for my custom Input here
        ...

        // Try to call Angular's Input descriptor
        Input(inputName)(prototype, memberName);

        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

This seems to work, and whatever changes I make at the specified point (e.g. adding functionality to the setter, etc.) works fine. However, Angular doesn't recognize the `Input`. When looking in [Augury](https://augury.angular.io/), I don't see the input listed with all the others; when I try to use it from other components, it fails saying the input doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong here? Stepping into the `Input()` code, it seems to be called correctly.

I'm using Angular 2.4.4.

Comment: Note that in the line `Input(inputName)(prototype, memberName);`, this is similar but not identical to the usage the TypeScript compiler has. The TypeScript compiler uses the return code as a descriptor if it is non-empty. I couldn't do the same because I need to use my own descriptor, however that shouldn't be a problem because angular's `Input` does not create a custom descriptor, i.e. it returns `undefined`.